# Can I ask for a list of advice?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I were going to ask a question: "What are the good things to do when taking on a new position in a new company?" but I thought that there would be no clear answer or an answer would be an aggregation of user answer.

Hence my question: can I ask for for a list of tips? How should I phrase it or limit the scope of answers?

Comment: similar discussion at other site meta: [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to be pretty specific about what you want more than the obvious:

1) Do what your hiring manager tells you (e.g. you supply references, banking details, etc.)
2) Follow the onboarding process for your new company when you join
3) Perform whatever tasks your manager gives you
4) Be on time
5) Be clean
6) Be polite

A lot of answers will either be opinion-based or too vague to be really useful.

Comment: or be useful as more of a blog post. Is the idea behind WP@SE is to create specific answer to each of these areas?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking: no. [List questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124450/what-is-the-definition-of-a-list-question) are unsuitable for our format and explicitly asking for a list of "some of the things to do" would be a prime candidate for closure.

Rephrasing the question to "*How do I accomplish X?*" or "*What should I keep in mind when Y?*" largely avoids that. Answers might still be in a list format and are unlikely to ever be exhaustive but can still be valuable. The distinction is between asking a question you want an answer to and asking a question you want a list of possible answers for. It's a fine line but as long as your question has a specific goal you're generally fine.

That said, the question you have in mind has in fact been asked before:

- [First proper job - Making good first impressions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/48276/first-proper-job-making-good-first-impressions)
- [Ways of Making a good impression in the new job](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3384/ways-of-making-a-good-impression-in-the-new-job)